# How to fix the enter key?

Tags: android-studio

[image]

I am creating an app for Android.  <kbd>Enter</kbd> key does not work. I don't know what happened. It does not make a new line. The problem is on Android studio only.

Comment: Can you please share what have you tried to achieve this?

Comment: Please be more specific in your question about the issue which you are facing. It will be more helpful for understanding.  You must have a look at how to ask a question in StackOverflow. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: As per your screenshot, it seems that somehow you have pressed the "Insert" key from the keyboard. Press it again then you can see the blinking cursor which works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are in overtype mode. This is basic functionality in most editors. Hit the Insert key ("Ins"/"INS") on your keyboard to switch back to the insert mode.

Usually a restart of the application also resets the mode to the (default) insert mode.